# Google Cloud SDK documentation

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have just started looking at Google Cloud. I have been following [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/) to try to setup the system.

I can successfully download the tar file, I can successfully run install.sh, however when I run the following command I get some unusual behaviour:

```
./google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud init
```

1) I agree to login - fine.
2) It brings up a page where I need to choose one of my accounts, which I do.
3) It brings up a website saying:

```
Google Cloud SDK wants to access your Google Account
```

I then hit Allow.
4) This is where it all goes wrong.   It then tries to go to a website such as the following:

```
http://localhost:8085/?code=4/tQD6sXNDlkpcdFUctB7ZgKKuj7T1Aiqev4o7zGaDVpctit6zrqFfWbnAXSo_zFTVjo4_VyxrUlUtq8IgsRAS7M0&scope=openid%20email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/accounts.reauth%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me
```

The website displays something saying 'This site can't be reached'.

This seems strange to me.   Why is Google attempting to access http://localhost:8085 ? Surely it should be going to some kind of Google site.

If you could offer any help or advice, I would very much appreciate it.   Please bear in mind that I am new to Google Cloud and I would need some very basic help. I am trying to setup a simple website with something like "hello world" with html/css and python.

If you know of any alternative tutorials that work, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: From the 4st state you described seems that it try to authenticate the connection but there is something that is blocked it, are you using a proxy or something on your firewall rule? Disable it and try again. I am guessing the account you used is granted on your project ?

Comment: The redirect to http://localhost:8085 is normal. This is how OAuth works when you are authenticating on localhost. What OS? Do you have a firewall or proxy enabled? You can also init via `gcloud init --console-only`

Comment: sorry for not getting back sooner on this.   I had a bit of a manic Christmas, and should be able to start looking at it soon.   I must admit that I forgot to check the firewall, so will take a look soon.   Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem as you. I solved it by using `gcloud auth login --no-launch-browser`